# Pandas groupby - Expanding mean by column value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Pandas and somewhat lost on what to do here. I have a dataframe imported from a csv, which (heavily simplified) look like this:

```
date = ['2013-08-10','2013-08-10','2013-08-10','2013-08-10','2013-08-10',
        '2013-08-10','2013-08-10','2013-08-10','2013-08-10','2013-08-10']
event = ['213','213','213','213','214','214','214','215','215','215']
side = ['A','B','B','B','A','B','A','B','A','B',]
value = [0.193,0.193,0.092,0.027,0.027,0.058,0.027,0.079,0.193,0.159]

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(event,date,side,value),
                  columns=['event','date','side','value'])

  event        date side  value
0   213  2013-08-10    A  0.193
1   213  2013-08-10    B  0.193
2   213  2013-08-10    B  0.092
3   213  2013-08-10    B  0.027
4   214  2013-08-10    A  0.027
5   214  2013-08-10    B  0.058
6   214  2013-08-10    A  0.027
7   215  2013-08-10    B  0.079
8   215  2013-08-10    A  0.193
9   215  2013-08-10    B  0.159
```

What I want is to sum the values corresponding to each side for every event. This I have achieved with groupby:

```
groupby = df.groupby(['event','side']).sum()

            value
event side       
213   A     0.193
      B     0.312
214   A     0.054
      B     0.058
215   A     0.193
      B     0.238
```

But I also want to add a new column with the expanding mean for each side, like this:

```
            value
event side          roll_mean
213   A     0.193   0
      B     0.312   0
214   A     0.054   0.193
      B     0.058   0.312
215   A     0.193   0.124
      B     0.238   0.185
```

Note that every event has two side, but it's not always A and B. What I want is something like excel's mean.if function, which computes the expanding mean for all values of the current side, applied to all previous rows. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: what kind of window are you thinking of for the rolling mean? And why would the rolling mean be zero at the edges? Wouldnt it rather be null as not computable?

Comment: The window would be any previous events, and yes it should be null.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're actually looking for an expanding mean, not a rolling mean. An expanding mean considers every previous value. I'll start where you left off:

```
In [63]: res = df.groupby(['event','side']).sum()
In [64]: res
Out[64]: 
            value
event side       
213   A     0.193
      B     0.312
214   A     0.054
      B     0.058
215   A     0.193
      B     0.238
```

Now we want to groupby `side` and take the expanding mean:

```
In [65]: res['expanding_mean'] = res.groupby(level='side').apply(pd.expanding_mean).shift(2)
In [66]: res
Out[66]: 
            value  expanding_mean
event side                       
213   A     0.193             NaN
      B     0.312             NaN
214   A     0.054          0.1930
      B     0.058          0.3120
215   A     0.193          0.1235
      B     0.238          0.1850
```

Your result needs to be `shift`ed by 2 since you want the mean to include all *previous* ones, and not the current one (make sure this is what you actually want, this seems a bit funny). You can replace the `shift(2)` with `len(res.index.levels[1])` to make it a bit more general in case you have more than 2 sides.

Comment: Didn't know about expanding mean. This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: As it turned out, this is not what I needed. Later in the dataframe different sides than A and B turn up, which complicate things. What I need is something like excel's mean.if() function where the condition is that the value belong to the same side, A, B, C etc. I hope you understand.

Comment: That is, the shift does not work since the differents side do not turn up in any particular order.

Answer (score 0):

I added more 'sides' to your dataframe, so it works when the results aren't just 'A' or 'B'. Is this what you want?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
date = ['2013-08-10','2013-08-10','2013-08-10','2013-08-10','2013-08-10',
        '2013-08-10','2013-08-10','2013-08-10','2013-08-10','2013-08-10']
event = ['213','213','213','213','214','214','214','215','215','215']
side = ['A','B','A','B','C','A','C','A','C','A',]
value = [0.193,0.193,0.092,0.027,0.027,0.058,0.027,0.079,0.193,0.159]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(event,date,side,value)),
                columns=['event','date','side','value'])
print(df)

event        date side  value
0   213  2013-08-10    A  0.193
1   213  2013-08-10    B  0.193
2   213  2013-08-10    A  0.092
3   213  2013-08-10    B  0.027
4   214  2013-08-10    C  0.027
5   214  2013-08-10    A  0.058
6   214  2013-08-10    C  0.027
7   215  2013-08-10    A  0.079
8   215  2013-08-10    C  0.193
9   215  2013-08-10    A  0.159


ds = df.groupby(['event','side']).sum()
print(ds)

        value
event side       
213   A     0.285
      B     0.220
214   A     0.058
      C     0.054
215   A     0.238
      C     0.193

ds.reset_index(inplace=True)
ds['exp_mean'] = np.NaN
for s in ds.side.unique():
    ndx = ds[ds.side==s].index
    ds.ix[ndx,'exp_mean'] = pd.expanding_mean(ds.ix[ndx,'value']).shift(1)
ds.set_index(['event', 'side'], inplace=True, drop=True)
print(ds)

            value  exp_mean
event side                 
213   A     0.285       NaN
      B     0.220       NaN
214   A     0.058    0.2850
      C     0.054       NaN
215   A     0.238    0.1715
      C     0.193    0.0540
```

Answer (score 0):

See this pandas commit (lines 60-78): https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/699424027fb657192541bcd0c3d9f9b7d26f2300

```
`You can now use ``.rolling(..)`` and ``.expanding(..)`` as methods on groupbys. 
These return another deferred object (similar to what ``.rolling()`` and 
``.expanding()`` do on ungrouped pandas objects). You can then operate
 on these ``RollingGroupby`` objects in a similar manner.

Previously you would have to do this to get a rolling window mean per-group:
 .. ipython:: python
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1] * 20 + [2] * 12 + [3] * 8,
                      'B': np.arange(40)})
   df
 .. ipython:: python
    df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x.rolling(4).B.mean())
 Now you can do:
 .. ipython:: python
    df.groupby('A').rolling(4).B.mean()`
```